# Sending data over p2p network in Android

Tags: android, client, wifi, server, p2p

I am doing some experiment in Android and I am not able to send data from one device to another. I needed to have a p2p network so that if one device receives the data then another devices can get the data from those devices also which has already received the data.
I have also studied and seen videos about wifi but they only tell about scanning wifi and start/stop of wifi.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Below we have two Thread classes to send and recieve file...

```
public class FileRead extends Thread {
        Socket socket;
        String name;

        FileRead(Socket socket,String filename) {
            this.socket=socket;
        this.name=name;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        File file=null;
        try {


            file = new File (filePath,name);

            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            byte[] bytes;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                bytes = (byte[])ois.readObject();

                fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.write(bytes);

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.i("INFO","class not found exception");

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    }


public class FileSend extends Thread {
    Socket socket;
File file;
    FileSend(Socket socket,File f){
        this.socket= socket;
        file=f;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {



        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(bytes);
            oos.flush();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.i("INFO","  file not found exception");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("INFO","  io exception exception");
        }
    }
```

We use to send file between two binded socket on two diffrent device.
start these thread by code below

```
File file = new File(FILEPATH+File.separator+FILENAME);
    FileSend fileSend = new FileSend(socket,file);
    fileSend.start();//write file

    FileRead fileRead =new FileRead(socket,RECIEVEDFILENAME);
    fileRead.start();//read file
```

Comment: This code you should use if u have knowledge of native socket programming in java...